# Add current position to the jump list the first time <C-u> or <C-d> is pressed

Tags: cursor-motions, navigation, jumplist

I'm often using <C-u> and <C-d> to quickly navigate around in my code (I don't like using { and } since they're hard to type on my layout). One thing that annoys me is that <C-u> and <C-d> don't interact with the jump list.

I know I could fix this by something like

```
nnoremap <C-u> m'<C-u>
nnoremap <C-d> m'<C-d>
```

but that would of course extend the jump list every time, which is annoying as well. I only care about the position that I started from, not the intermediate ones.

I thought that the best way to fix this would be that <C-u> and <C-d> only extend the jump list **if the previous command was not <C-u> or <C-d>**. This way, it wouldn't clutter the jump list but I could still jump back to where I started from. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way yet to check what the last command I typed was.

Comment: If you know you are going come back you can just put down a mark, e.g. `mm`. However, i find that many times I was writing code in a place, then I needed to look somewhere. So I either open a new window to read/review another area or I use `g;` to move backwards through the change-list.

Answer (score 5):

This code implements what you suggest, saving the initial position into the jump list when using a series of Ctrl+D or Ctrl+U motions.

```
function! SaveJump(motion)
  if exists('#SaveJump#CursorMoved')
    autocmd! SaveJump
  else
    normal! m'
  endif
  let m = a:motion
  if v:count
    let m = v:count.m
  endif
  execute 'normal!' m
endfunction

function! SetJump()
  augroup SaveJump
    autocmd!
    autocmd CursorMoved * autocmd! SaveJump
  augroup END
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <C-u> :<C-u>call SaveJump("\<lt>C-u>")<CR>:call SetJump()<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <C-d> :<C-u>call SaveJump("\<lt>C-d>")<CR>:call SetJump()<CR>
```

The way this works is by creating a `CursorMoved` autocmd to track whether the cursor was moved in between a sequence of Ctrl+D and Ctrl+U movements.

Since using a Ctrl+D/Ctrl+U will create the autocmd, we don't need an additional flag to tell whether the last motion was a Ctrl+D/Ctrl+U, we can simply check whether the autocmd exists. If it does, we just remove it, if it doesn't, then we know we're the first of a sequence, so we set a mark with `m'` to get us into the jumplist.

The autocmd itself just needs to reset itself, since it's triggered for a motion other than Ctrl+D/Ctrl+U, so just dropping the autocmd will make the next Ctrl+D/Ctrl+U recognize it's the first of a sequence.

Note that the code had to be broken into two separate functions, since the first function (actually executing the motion itself) needs to complete in order for the motion to have effect. Setting the autocmd in that same function has the effect of it triggering right as the function completes, which prevents us from using it to detect repeated motions of the same kind...

This idea could be extended, for instance to check whether the cursor has been moved within the same line and not reset the motion block in that case. (For example, if you'd like to allow for horizontal motion, perhaps to use `$` to inspect the end of a line under `nowrap` in between a sequence of Ctrl+D/Ctrl+U motions.) It shouldn't be hard to extend it to cover other similar motions as well.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: This is amazing. Thank you!

Comment: You are a vim wizard fibranden! For anyone using neovim, this works wonders along with: `vim.opt.jumpoptions = "stack"`